# VS2010, scanf, strange behaviour

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, scanf

I'm converting some source from VC6 to VS2010. The code is written in C++/CLI and it is an MFC application. It includes a line:

```
BYTE mybyte;
sscanf(source, "%x", &mybyte);
```

Which is fine for VC6 (for more than 15 years) but causing problems in VS2010 so I created some test code.

```
void test_WORD_scanf()
{
    char *source = "0xaa";
    char *format = "%x";
    int  result = 0;

    try
    {
        WORD pre    = -1;
        WORD target = -1;
        WORD post   = -1;

        printf("Test (pre scan):  stack: pre=%04x, target=%04x, post=%04x, sourse='%s', format='%s'\n", pre, target, post, source, format);
        result = sscanf(source, format, &target);
        printf("Test (post scan): stack: pre=%04x, target=%04x, post=%04x, sourse='%s', format='%s'\n", pre, target, post, source, format);
        printf("result=%x", result);

        // modification suggested by Werner Henze.
        printf("&pre=%x sizeof(pre)=%x, &target=%x, sizeof(target)=%x, &post=%x, sizeof(post)=%d\n", &pre, sizeof(pre), &target, sizeof(target), &post, sizeof(post));
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        printf("Exception: Bad luck!\n");
    }
}
```

Building this (in DEBUG mode) is no problem. Running it gives strange results that I cannot explain. First, I get the output from the two printf statemens as expected. Then a get a run time waring, which is the unexpected bit for me.

```
Test (pre scan):  stack: pre=ffff, target=ffff, post=ffff, source='0xaa', format='%x'
Test (post scan): stack: pre=ffff, target=00aa, post=ffff, source='0xaa', format='%x'
result=1

Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'target' was corrupted.
```

Using the debugger I found out that the run time check failure is triggered on returning from the function. Does anybody know where the run time check failure comes from? I used Google but can't find any suggestion for this.

In the actual code it is not a WORD that is used in sscanf but a BYTE (and I have a BYTE version of the test function). This caused actual stack corruptions with the "%x" format (overwriting variable pre with 0) while using "%hx" (what I expect to be the correct format) is still causing some problems in overwriting the lower byte of variable prev.

Any suggestion is welcome.

Note: I edited the example code to include the return result from sscanf()

Kind regards,

Andre Steenveld.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sscanf` with `%x` [writes an `int`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ttkkkhh.aspx). If you provide the address of a `BYTE` or a `WORD` then you get a buffer overflow/stack overwrite. `%hx` will [write a `short int`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdb9w69d.aspx).

The solution is to have an int variable, let `sscanf` write to that and then set your `WORD` or `BYTE` variable to the read value.

```
int x;
sscanf("%x", "0xaa", x);
BYTE b = (BYTE)x;
```

BTW, for your test and the message

> Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'target' was corrupted.

you should also print out the addresses of the variables and you'll probably see that the compiler added some padding/security check space between the variables pre/target/post.

Comment: That solved the problem. I assumed sizeof(WORD) == sizeof(int) which is wrong! Silly me. :+)

Comment: I tested your remark on the padding/secutiry check spaces and found it. A helpfull suggestion, thanks again.

Comment: @PapaAtHome I am glad I was able to help. Feel free to upvote my answer if you think it was helpful :-).